# How to pass malloced variable into a struct to a newly created struct in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Let's take this example:

```
struct args{
    char *fname;
}

int main(void){
    struct args tArg;
    tArg.fname = malloc(10);
    strcpy(tArg.fname, "ciao");
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, thread, (void *)&tArg);
    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    free(tArg.fname);
    return 0;
}

void *thread(void *p1Arguments){
    struct args *p1 = p1Arguments;
    printf("%s\n", p1->fname);
}
```

the `printf` into the `thread` leads the program to a segfault because there is nothing into `p1->fname`.
What can i do to pass a malloc'ed string?

**EDIT**: i'm sorry i forgot to write the `pthread_join`

Comment: The problem is that you need to synchronize "free()".  SUGGESTIONS: 1) add a "getchar()" - easy, 2) do a "pthread_join()" in main

Answer (score 1):

It looks like:

1) You're correctly allocating and initializing "fname" in struct tArg

2) You're also correctly passing tArg into your thread

... BUT ...

3) Your main program is *deallocating* "fname" before the thread accesses it (bad!)

SUGGESTION:

Put a "getchar()" after you create the thread (and *BEFORE* you call "free()"), so that main will wait for the user to hit "ENTER" before it frees and before it exits.

Answer (score 1):

You passed it correctly.

**You `free(tArg.fname);`, But thread is trying to use `tArg.fname`.**

```
// ...

pthread_create(&p1, NULL, thread, (void *)&tArg);

pthread_join(p1, NULL); // <-- PUT THIS AND GIVE A MOMENT TO THREAD

free(tArg.fname);

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than waiting for the thread to complete, as stated by @Claudiu you must also cast the `p1Arguments` - this is one of the few places where a cast is necessary in C language.

Comment: why is a cast necessary here? could you go into a bit more detail?

Comment: @Claudiu - an old neuron in my brain told me so. I ran into a problem casting `void *` to `struct *` which contained a `char *` - and things went messy. It was a bad experience debugging for 8 hours. Casting somehow magically solved the problem.

Comment: @Claudiu by the way your answer was good. Why did you delete it?

Comment: he edited his question to show he was already doing the `pthread_join`, so it must be something else

Answer (score 1):

The thought is

```
pthread_create(&p1, NULL, thread, (void *)&tArg);
free(tArg.fname);
```

is incorrect.

The thread should do the free bit.

And the main does a join

Comment: "main does join" - excellent idea.  "thread should do the free" - no necessarily.  In general, it would be cleaner to "free" at the same level as the original "malloc()".  In other words, I would prefer to keep it the way it is - just don't "free" prematurely.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 - I think you could be right. But my philosophy it is a relay race and sometimes you need to pass the baton on.

Answer (score 0):

It may be stack problem.

targ you have passed is created on stack. when you pass tArg address (which is on stack of main program), thread has its own stack section. I suggest you two solutions.

1> try by malloc tArg itself. declare it as pointer to struct.
2> or define tArg as global variable, which will force it to allocated on global data section and not stack section.